# Update content file flutter without truncate

Tags: flutter, mobile

I´m working with files in my application, I´m taking this article as example [https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), I can read and write the file succesfully, my estructure is the next

```
{
'products' : {my_items...},
'data_customer' : {info_customer...}
}
```

But my problem is, It´s possible update the content from 'data_customer', preserving 'products' information?

I tried use the FileMode.writeOnlyAppend, but this only append the info in the end of file, for example

```
{
'products' : {my_items...},
'data_customer' : {info_customer...}
'data_customer' : {new_info_customer...}
}
```

I just want to update the information. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as string and use **json.decode()** method to convert it as Map<Sting, dynamic> then change the data and rewrite to the file after decoding it to JSON using **json.encode()** method.